# Запуск приложения в gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, linux

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно запустить консольное приложение в окне gnome-terminal, вызывая его из другого окна gnome-terminal. Подскажите, через какие параметры это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим man 1 gnome-terminal. Там первым параметром идет

```
-e, --command=STRING
                 Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal.
```

Т.е. вызываем так

```
gnome-terminal -e ./my_prog
```

P.S. С параметрами

```
gnome-terminal -e './my_prog param1 param2'
```

Comment: А передавать параметры запускаемой программе при этом можно?

Comment: Почему-то не всякое приложение хочет запускаться. Есть какие-то критерии для запуска?

Comment: Видимо у Вас проблема в том, что вместе с завершением приложения закрывается и терминал. Пишите что-то вроде:

    gnome-terminal -e "sh -c \\"echo hello $PATH; pwd; cat\\""

cat будет ждать ввода и не даст терминалу закрыться.

Comment: Как передать такие параметры в execlp в с++?

Comment: Навскидку 

    execlp ("gnome-terminal","gnome-terminal","-e","sh -c \"echo hello $PATH; pwd; cat\"", NULL);

Подставит ли вызываемый **sh** вместо $PATH его значение из текущего environment, честно, не знаю. Надо пробовать. Понятно, что при запуске из командной строки эту подстановку делает текущий sh.

Попробовал из командной строки

    gnome-terminal -e "sh -c 'echo hello $PATH; pwd; cat'"

$PATH раскрыт. Значит должен подставить. Сорри, лень перебивать коммент, поэтому так длинно.

Comment: @carapuz, а неужели не получилось ? Вы снова такой же вопрос задали.